# Как вернуться в верх определенного элемента на странице?

Tags: javascript

Создал функцию, знаю что `.scrollTo(0,0)` работает для `window`, но как применить это к элементу на странице?  Подскажите пожалуйста

```js
function returnToTopElement(clickingObjId, element){
 let clickOn = document.getElementById(clickingObjId);
 let topElement = document.getElementById(element);
 clickOn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  topElement.scrollTo(0,0);
 });
};

returnToTopElement("top-button", "elem-b");
```

```css
.elem-a{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  color: black;
}
.elem-b{
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #263B42;
  color: white;
}
.top-button{
  margin-top: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.top-button:hover{
  background-color: #b2b2b2;
}
```

```html
<div>  
  <div class="elem-a"> a </div>
  <div class="elem-b" id="elem-b"> 

  b

  <p class="top-button" id="top-button"> Return to the top </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас же есть 2 параметра `(0, 0)`, вот и передавайте туда те числа, которые вам нужны

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит, так как мне нужно использовать функцию на разных страницах, где высота элементов будет различаться.

Comment: так узнавайте это число динамически